# Why does Azure Stream Analytics outputs data to seperate files?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, powerbi, azure-data-lake, azure-stream-analytics

Why does Stream Analytics create separate files when using Azure Data Lake or Azure Blob Storage? Some times the stream runs for days in one file, while other times every day a couple of new files are made. It seems rather random?

I output the data to CSV, the query stays the same, and every now and then there is a new file generated.

I would prefer it to have one large CSV file, because I want to be able to run long-term statistics using Power BI on the data, but this seems impossible when it are all separate files with a seemingly random name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs - this page has details about when a new file is created. In your case, it is most likely due to an internal restart.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems that is indeed the case. However working with the data as a whole in Azure Data Lake or Blob Storage makes this pretty hard in Power BI. How can I receive all files as one dataset in Power BI? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: In Power BI, you can import the data from a "folder" and combine all data files together.

Comment: @JSAzure do you have an example or documentation for that? If that is the case, my problem is solved :-)

Comment: Here's a tutorial for Excel file: it will work with CSV as well: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/combining-excel-files-hosted-on-a-sharepoint-folder/ The only requirement is that PowerBI can access to the folder. I haven't tried directly with Blob container though.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to get it running. I used a combination of your link and the following link: http://www.dutchdatadude.com/loading-multiple-json-files-using-power-query/